# Determine whether the first $2015$ terms of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n^{-2}$ is an overestimate or underestimate

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If we used the first 2015 terms to estimate the sum of the convergent series $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$ would it be an overestimate or an underestimate?

I really have no idea where to start with this so could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternating series of strictly decreasing in absolute value terms. So whenever you add a positive term, you are overestimating. Whenever you add a negative term, you are underestimating.

So this question is asking you whether or not you understand that fact (it's the key idea in the proof of the alternating series test for convergence) and whether or not you are capable of determining the sign of the $2015$th term.

Comment: But how can I look at this convergent series and determine the sum? Is there a technique or trick which I need to apply? Something to do with odd/even numbers